Counting Active Transactions in SQL: Issues with Status Logic in Time Series Data
I am trying to create a SQL query to count active transactions month by month from a transaction_status table. Each transaction_id can have multiple statuses, with two key statuses: ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS (when the transaction is active) and ENDORSEMENT_CLOSED_SUCCESS (when the transaction is closed).
Problem:
The challenge I'm facing is ensuring that:

A transaction should only be counted as active if it has the ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS status and does not have the ENDORSEMENT_CLOSED_SUCCESS status at any point after that.

If a transaction is closed in a particular month, it should not be counted as active in the following months, but it should still be counted in the months where it was active.

Additionally, we have a parallel transaction table that tracks the last_status of each transaction_id. The monthly count of active transactions from the transaction_status table should match the count of transactions with last_status = 'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS' from the transaction table.


Despite multiple attempts, the results are consistently incorrect, with the total count being higher than expected.
What I Tried:
Here’s the query I’m using to try and count the active transactions per month:
WITH transactions AS (
    SELECT 
        transaction_id,
        MIN(CASE WHEN status = 'ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS' THEN created_at END) AS start_date,
        MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'ENDORSEMENT_CLOSED_SUCCESS' THEN created_at END) AS end_date
    FROM 
        transaction_status
    GROUP BY 
        transaction_id
),
active_transactions AS (
    SELECT 
        transaction_id,
        start_date
    FROM 
        transactions
    WHERE 
        end_date IS NULL OR end_date > CURRENT_DATE
),
months AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) AS month_start
    FROM 
        transaction_status
)

SELECT 
    m.month_start,
    COUNT(DISTINCT at.transaction_id) AS active_transactions
FROM 
    months m
LEFT JOIN 
    active_transactions at
ON 
    at.start_date <= m.month_start
GROUP BY 
    m.month_start
ORDER BY 
    m.month_start;

The data in the "status" column of the "transaction_status" table is output like this:



transaction_id
status
created_at




1222
ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS
2024-03-01


1222
ENDORSEMENT_CLOSED_SUCCESS
2024-10-11


1333
ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS
2024-01-15


1444
ENDORSEMENT_SUCCESS
2024-02-21


1444
ENDORSEMENT_CLOSED_SUCCESS
2024-09-15



Expected Output:



month_start
active_transactions




2024-03-01
30


2024-04-01
65



For example, based on the data above, the expected output for the month of March 2023 should be:
What I Expected: I expected the query to return the number of active transactions for each month, with totals that would match the last_status count from the parallel transaction table.
What Actually Resulted: The total count returned by the query is higher than expected, and it does not align with the counts from the transaction table.
